# How does Nautilus mount a partition as normal user?

Tags: linux, permissions, mount, nautilus

I can only run the `mount` command with superuser privileges.

How can Nautilus do the same with normal access? How do things work inside?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what it is you're trying to mount, but if memory servers anything that is listed in /etc/fstab can be mounted by anyone. This is so that sdcards and cds can be mounted.

Comment: I'm using ubuntu. I couldn't find any file that named /etc/mount

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I've edited my post. It's /etc/fstab not /etc/mount